# Internet Explorer, when highlighting text it changes font and/or size

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, fonts

When highlighting text with IE 8 on a webpage that I'm currently developing the font changes and/or sometimes the size. The same thing happens sometimes when I hover over the menu.

This is how my css looks like and I don't know why the error occurs? One more thing that is very strange is that I have installed Windows 7 with paralells on my osx and the error does not occur there but only on PC computers. I have tried changing fonts but with no help...

This is my css:

```
body {
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#wrapper, .wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
    background: url('http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/120920_scam_banner.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#header div {
    width: 900px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
}

#header div a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    height: 150px;
}



#header div a:hover {
    background: none;
}

#section {

}

#menu {
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    padding: 20px 25px 0 0;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    text-align: right;
}

#menu a, a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mp-formdiv {
    float: right;
}

img {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#menu a:hover, a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}

.menu li {
    margin: 3px 0;
    text-align: right;
}

#menu h3 {
    line-height: 52px;
}

#menu .artists {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#menu-artists li {

}

#content {
    float: right; 
    width: 670px;
    padding: 20px 0 50px 20px;
}

#footer {
    overflow:hidden;
    clear: both;
}

#white_footer {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 20px;
}

#footer_content {
    height: 20px;
}

.store {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#the_store {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* FONTS */




h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 0%;
}

h1.storefront {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#content p strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#content p img {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

#content p img:after {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#subscribe_mail input[type=text]{
    width: 85px;
    height: 12px;
    font-size: 0.60em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

#subscribe_mail input[type=text]:focus {
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

#subscribe_mail input[type=submit] {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    float: left;
}

.mp-message, .mp-loading {
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

.MailPressFormName {
    display: none;
}

#artist_info {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

.more-less {
    background: #000;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#artist_less {
    display: none;
}

.gallery-icon a:hover {
    background: none;
}

.gallery dl {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.gallery dl dd {
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

.newsletterH {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Firefox's Firebug plugin to see where the styles are coming from.  IE provides a less friendly developer tool window that does something similar (I only use this if the style issue is only occurring in IE).  I'd check your :hover and :focus rules first since those would cause things to happen on hover or select.